# Poll and Select against polling manually [SPEED]

Tags: c, performance, select, polling, latency

I have developed an embedded system (Linux and C) that reads two sensors (5Hz and 200Hz) polling manually, checking if there is data available in both files.

Now, I would like to use Poll or Select POSIX functions to save CPU usage. I have been reading about it and about some possible latencies in sockets. I would like to know if poll and select functions are slow or just this "latency" I have read is just insignificant.

The sensor sends data each 5 ms and the algorithms could take 1-2 ms (Kalman filter). So the system has 2-3 ms until the next sensor sample or it will be too slow for my application.

Comment: please define "slow"

Comment: I read that It is possible to get a 5s latency using sockets. In my case, using sensors, I haven't seen any latency. The sensor sends data each 5milis and the algorithms could take 1-2millis (kalman filter). So the system has 2-3 milis until the next sensor sample.

Comment: The device that you read from (serial port?) should support the select() system call. And the "latency" that you are worried about is only one system call (per one or two read()s)

Answer (score 1):

Both poll and select mechanisms are intended to serve same purposes. Go through [this](https://www.ulduzsoft.com/2014/01/select-poll-epoll-practical-difference-for-system-architects/) link. This will give understanding with respect to the performance in depth for both mechanism. After that you would be able to take decision.

For `Poll` mechanism go through [**man poll**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) page for more information.

For `select` mechanism go through **[man select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)** page for more information. I would suggest to go through the `Multithreaded applications section`of it.

Look at `epoll` mechanism as well. Which can help you broaden your implementation thoughts.